# Vector space of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Good afternoon everyone, I am trying to calculate the following quotient vector space $\mathbb{M_3(R)}/S$, Where $S$ is the space of symmetric matrices of order 3, that is $S=\{A\in\mathbb{M_3(R)}: A=A^t\}$, $A^t$ means transposed matrix of $A$.

My work:

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices such that $A,B\in \mathbb{M_3(R)}$, We say that $A \sim B$ iff $A-B \in S$. But I do not know how to continue, that is, I do not know how to make this happen. I need to find the equivalence class of a matrix $A \in \mathbb{M_3(R)}$. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Hint: antisymmetric matrices (That's $M = -M^T$)

Comment: @user251257 Excuse me, but I do not get your idea, how can this fact help me with the exercise?

Comment: Each square matrix is a unique sum of a symmetric matrix and antisymmetric matrix. After you have divided out the symmetric matrices, what happens?

Comment: @user251257 I think there is an antisymmetric matrix, but my question is how to raise the quotient space and most importantly find the equivalence class of a matrix A. Can you help me with this please? I am a beginner.

Comment: Well the elements of $\mathbf M_3 / S$ are equivalence classes. But each equivalence class can be represented by an element of itself, which can be selected such that it is antisymmetric.

Comment: @user251257 How could it be selected? Could you go deeper a little more please? How can I make it $A-B \in S$? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

**hint**

We can write 
$$ A=\frac{1}{2}\left(A-A^t\right)+ \frac{1}{2}\left(A+A^t\right)$$
The second matrix on the right is symmetric. Therefore
$$ A \equiv \frac{1}{2}\left(A-A^t\right) \pmod{S}.$$
Observe that $A-A^t$ is a skew-symmetric matrix.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution, but then how specifically is defined the equivalence class of a Matrix $A$ 3x3 in the quotient, $[A]=[1/2(A-A^t)]$?

Comment: @DanielaRondón this means the equivalence class of a matrix$A$ will consist of all matrices of the form $1/2(A-A^t)+M$, where $M$ is any symmetric matrix.

Comment: @DanielaRondón so for the specific matrix you have put in the comments below, first compute the matrix $1/2(A-A^t)$ and then any symmetric matrix can be added to this matrix to get all possible matrices equivalent to your matrix $A$.

Comment: Thank you very much really!. Do you know that I am very interested in learning about the vector space quotient? Could you recommend a book, video or some reading where you can learn this topic?

Comment: @DanielaRondón I cannot think of a specific book because the idea of quotients is a very general idea. A while ago I had seen a link to these notes https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/4063-5023/4063-5023-l13.pdf perhaps you will find them useful.

Comment: I am doing a similar exercise, in this case: $\mathbb{M_3(R)}/UT$ Where $UT$ is the subspace of the upper triangular matrices of order 3. I suspect that any matrix $A$ can be written as a sum of an upper triangular matrix and a lower triangular matrix respectively, but I do not know?

Answer (score 3):

Let $T=\{ A \in \mathbb M_3 \mid A^T = -A \}$ the space of antisymmetric matrices. It is easy to see that $S\cap T = \{0\}$. In fact, both spaces together span $\mathbb M_3$ as for each $A$ we have
$$ A = \underbrace{\frac 12 (A+A^T)}_{\in S} + \underbrace{\frac12(A-A^T)}_{\in T}. $$

Now, let $A,B\in \mathbb M_3$ with $A-B\in S$. Then, we have
$$ S \ni A - B - \frac12(A+A^T) + \frac12(B+B^T) = \frac12(A-A^T) - \frac12(B-B^T) \in T.$$
That is the antisymmetric part of $A$ and $B$ agree. Thus, we can represent each equivalence class in $\mathbb M_3 / S$ by the uniquely antisymmetric element in it.

Comment: Your answer is very appropriate, thank you very much, but what does it mean at the end of it? Perhaps with an example you will understand better, what would be the equivalence class of the following matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 &0 \\ 2 &-6 &8 \\ 4& 0 &-1 \end{pmatrix}$???

Comment: @DanielaRondón just add $S$ to it. Technically you can represent an equivalence class by any element of it. But here using an antisymmetric matrix just feels natural.